# Undefined as parameter, target of assignment

Tags: javascript, undefined

Basically two questions, both pertaining to the behavior of `undefined`.

Q1 Why is it that this fails with a reference error:

```
function hello(a){
      return true;  
      }  
//var abc = undefined;
hello(abc);
```

but this doesn't:

```
function hello(a){
      return true;  
      }  
var abc = undefined;
hello(abc);
```

Q2 Why is it that this is a valid assignment:

```
undefined = 10;
```

But these aren't:

```
null = 10;
"hello" = 10;
10 = 10;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Because `undefined` is a special *variable*

Comment: @zerkms Isn't it a primitive like `null`, integers etc?

Comment: no, it's a predefined variable - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.1

Comment: `window.undefined` is a **variable** with **value** `undefined`. Also interesting (maybe): http://es5.github.com/#x8.1.

Comment: @Felix Kling: it's easier to always think of it as of a variable, because I cannot think an example when you use a primitive value directly not a variable

Comment: @zerkms: True... according to http://es5.github.com/#x7.8, an `undefined` literal does not even exist.

Comment: @zerkms I get it, so `function foo(){return undefined;} foo() = 10;` is invalid, because `foo()` is the *value* `undefined`, whereas in `undefined = 10;` `undefined` represents a variable.

Comment: @Asad: in this particular case it's invalid because you can only assign to a variable. In C++ it's called lvalue, not sure about precise js term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you are not defining the key `'abc'` on the global object and thus you are having a reference error trying to access it. It is something like `'Name error'` in ruby and python saying that an identifier is `undefined`.

These two are equivalent and they both define the `'abc'` key on the global object, in your case this is `window`.

```
var abc = undefined;
var abc;
```

Defining undefined as an identifier works. It defines the window.undefined key not the undefined type. This means that:

```
undefined = 10;
var a;
alert(a); // Yeilds undefined
alert(window.undefined); // Yeilds 10
```

In order to perform undefined check, check the type of the identifier:

```
if (typeof identifier === 'undefined') // Performs undefined check
```

Because:

```
if (identifier === undefined) // Gives us unexpected results 
// if undefined has been assigned to
```

In addition undefined is not a primitive. While `0`, `'string'` are primitives. `null` is a special singleton object as pointed out in the comments. Those are not identifiers but actual values so you cannot assign to them by specification.

**Update regarding NaN:**

NaN is slightly different because it is a primitive (number). Trying to do the same with NaN yeilds:

```
>> typeof NaN
"number"
>> NaN = 'a'
"a"
>> 0 === NaN
false
>> 'a' === NaN
false
>> typeof NaN
"number"
>> NaN
NaN
```

Comment: 'null' isn't an actual primitive, but a special 'singleton object'

Comment: @SeanKinsey Thanks for the correction Sean. I knew it's an object, I didn't bother to check the spec though. My bad I will correct it.

Comment: It was intended as a primitive, but ended up as an object (as in typeof returning 'object') by mistake :/

Comment: @SeanKinsey All the fun stuff like typeof NaN being a number.

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics `NaN` is a variable like `undefined` as it turns out. It holds a value `NaN` that is of numeric type.

Comment: @Asad NaN is a slightly different case because it is a primitive. Check my update on that.

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics Yeah, so is `undefined` (the value). What's your point?

Comment: @Asad Undefined is moreso an identifier which does not have a value. NaN has a value.